# How to get the complete route schema in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Given a simple Express app

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/users/:userId', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.orginalUrl) // /users/1
    console.log(req.route.path) // /users/:userId
    res.json({})
})
```

It gives me the right and complete route schema `req.route.path`.
But if we use a router to abstract the first part of the URI then it doesn't give the full route schema anymore.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const users = express.Router()
    .get(':userId', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.orginalUrl) // /users/1
        console.log(req.route.path) // /:userId
        res.json({})
    })

app.use('/users', users)
```

It there a way to get `/users/:userId` while using routers?

### Edit

It seems that `@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express` has done this using some kind of monkey patching.

[Here is the code](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js-contrib/blob/main/plugins/node/opentelemetry-instrumentation-express/src/instrumentation.ts)

Comment: How about [`req.baseUrl`](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req) in conjunction with `req.route.path`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to concatenate baseUrl and path like this :

```
let fullPath = req.baseUrl + req.route.path;
```

Comment: If `req.baseUrl` contains a param, it will not get replaced by the original value:
```js
// If we use /John/hello, then req.baseUrl === '/John'
app.use('/:name', express.Router().get('/hello', (req, res) => res.json(req.baseUrl)))
```